# Give priority to background music ( itunes ) over avfoundation player node

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm using **`AVFoundation`** framework. Whenever the player plays the buffer, my background music gets stopped so I used below code to allow it to continue playing irrespective of the **`AVFoundation`** player.

```
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.mixWithOthers,.allowBluetooth])
try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
try audioSession.setActive(true)
```

It does work but the problem is the quality of the background music gets dramatically affected. The music don't have the bass effects anymore whenever the `AVPlayer` plays the buffer.

I want the background music uninterrupted while using `AVPlayer`. Is it possible?

**update** : I added full code if anyone wants to check. Can feel the difference in background itune music as soon as the app is opened or the session is activated when using this code.

```
class ViewCosdfntroller: UIViewController  {

    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    let mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.mixWithOthers,.allowBluetooth])
            try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch {
        }

        let input = engine.inputNode
        let bus = 0
        let inputFormat = input.outputFormat(forBus: bus)
        let recordingFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 11025.0, channels: 1, interleaved: false)

        engine.attach(player)
        engine.attach(mixer)
        engine.connect(input, to: mixer, format: input.outputFormat(forBus: 0))
        engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: recordingFormat)
        mixer.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(inputFormat.sampleRate * 0.4), format: inputFormat, block: { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in

            let Converter:AVAudioConverter = AVAudioConverter.init(from: inputFormat, to: recordingFormat!)!
            let newbuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: recordingFormat!,frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount((recordingFormat?.sampleRate)! * 0.4))
            let inputBlock : AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { (inNumPackets, outStatus) -> AVAudioBuffer? in
                outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
                let audioBuffer : AVAudioBuffer = buffer
                return audioBuffer
            }
            var error : NSError?
            Converter.convert(to: newbuffer!, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputBlock)
            self.player.scheduleBuffer(newbuffer!)

        })
        do {
            try! engine.start()
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this is some weird mixing quirk, the quality change you report may just be that recording categories change the default audio output device to the tiny, tinny receiver (because telephones, don't ask). Override this behaviour by adding `.defaultToSpeaker` to your `setCategory()` call:

```
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.mixWithOthers,.allowBluetooth, .defaultToSpeaker])
```

Comment: Awesome. there is still one problem :( the App Audio is not hearable ( very slightly ) when background music is playing. is it possible to increase the volume? i mean gain?

Comment: or probably it just looks like the app volume is low since the background music volume is high.?

Comment: funny... when i put the mic very close to the mouth its output is good and when i leave it hanging near the chin the output is a little low.

Comment: That sounds like a new, harder question.

Comment: I think its all working well. its like complaining that we cant hear each other in a dj club. so i prefer not to. Thanks!

Comment: I complain about that kind of stuff, but fair enough.

Comment: hey fistman, i came up with one more problem but fortunately solved those two. i set mixer.Outputvolume to more than 1.0 ( 10.0 ) apple says we can set only between 0.0 to 1.0 but its actually gaining when i set it more than 1.0 and that solves the problem which i commented earlier. second, the bluetooth was using HPP so the background music quality was  still bad when using external headset for that i changed .allowbluetooth to .allowbluetoothad2p and now everything works great. thanks again.

Comment: That's brilliant! A2DP makes sense too.

Comment: You mean HFP, don't you?

Comment: Ofcourse it is. Is it possible to set allow bluetooth option for recording and allow bluetootha2dp for playing?

Comment: To be more clear. While using .allowbluetooth the voice didn't have much background noise but the background quality got degraded and while using .allowblutootha2dp the voice recording at 44.1khz and it observes lot of background noise meanwhile the background music quality is better. It would be handy if I can set different options for recording and play back

Comment: Yes you can call setCategory with new options whenever you want.

Comment: yes i can set that but the problem is i am recording and playing back simultaneously so i have to figure out how to use bluetooth hfp input and bluetooth a2dp output to ensure good recording with high quality playback. unfortunately https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/15178#15178 i read something that its not possible as it select mic and output as a pair but its been few years do we got any enhancement already?

Comment: That really does look like bad news - the audio session “bag of flags” approach can’t handle anything even slightly sophisticated, and Bluetooth profile support is incomplete, non orthogonal and smeared out over some very surprising APIs. You’ll just have to try HFP in and A2DP our and (hopefully!) report back here. I guess you could file a radar too and hope for some improvements come WWDC2018.

Comment: will definitely do. Cheers.

Comment: https://sennheiseruk.happyfox.com/kb/article/175-different-bluetooth-profiles-a2dp-vs-hsp/  after reading this i felt hearbrokened. atleast before i thought my headset mic is just obversing some background noise actually it was not working at all due to the reasons mentioned in that article when using a2dp. i was not able to figured it out earlier because i was testing with the phone nearby when i put it away i found that that the bluetooth microphone is actually not working and it actually uses phone inbuilt microphone.

Comment: now am too confused that is it apple problem or bluetooth profiles problem. will there be any advanced bluetooth profile comes out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this one:

```
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryambient

> When you use this category, audio from other apps mixes with your audio

Comment: Thanks i will try . but there is one more thing , am also using bluetooth headset. so actually am using this code  ( try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.mixWithOthers,.allowBluetooth]) ) i just removed allowbluetooth so that others cant get confuse. can you able help me with it?